# How to determine which script that python is executing?

Tags: python, linux, process

There is an old Python web service running on linux server. I have the pid=12345, the script path is relative and there are many scripts with the same path name. How to determine which one is used by this web service (pid=12345) ?

eg:

```
# ps aux | grep 12345
www  12345  0.0  0.0 497952  1096 ?   S    Jan09   0:12 python ../www/server.py --port=20321 --mode=0 --processes=2 --threads=10 --logdir=./log/

# locate www/server.py
path_01/www/server.py
path_02/www/server.py
... a lot of files
```

Comment: Seems like multiple instances of same script are running.

Comment: @NitinPawar You are right. The server.py is a tornado. There are 3 processes. One is master, other two are workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do `sudo pwdx <your_pid>` in your case `sudo pwdx 12345` and you will get the full path.

Comment: Another solution:  `sudo ls -l /proc/pid/cwd`